# Jenkins auto deploy to Jboss AS 7.1.1 fails with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: jboss, jenkins, maven-deploy-plugin

I've been facing this error for few days, appreciate if somebody could kindly advise.

My pom is configured with jboss auto deploy plugin version 7.1.1.Final. When I build the project from jenkins it builds fine but cannot deploy to jboss, fails with below exception:

```
Oct 21, 2013 6:55:02 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA

Authenticating against security realm: ManagementRealm

Exception in thread "management-client-thread 1-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2271)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:140)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.StreamUtils.copyStream(StreamUtils.java:49)
    at     org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient$ReadAttachmentInputStreamRequestHandler.copyStream(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:226)
      at         org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient$ReadAttachmentInputStreamRequestHandler$1.execute(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:202)
    at     org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.AbstractMessageHandler$2$1.doExecute(AbstractMessageHandler.java:287)
    at         org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.AbstractMessageHandler$AsyncTaskRunner.run(AbstractMessageHandler.java:487)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
```

This is jvm setting I've got:
-Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

Thanks

Prash

Comment: Which JVM setting are you talking about? Jenkins server or Maven build? I guess you should give maven a little bit more memory.

Comment: As for me it looks like that there isn't enough memory for JBoss server. Try increasing JBoss' memory. Is parameter -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m - taken from JBoss config?

Comment: I encountered the same problem and solved it by 1. giving more memory to **Maven** (in OSX: `export MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx4096m`) and 2. giving more memory to the **runner** executing the maven configuration within my IDE (by changing VM Options in IntelliJ to: `-Xms64m -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m`)  --- So this is definitely a client related issue. Though it won't hurt to pass more memory to JBoss as well.

Comment: Thank you all for kind suggestions, yes I have solved it by adding more physical memory to the server, I didn't realise it was running only on just 1gb ram, increased to 2gb and it works fine. thanks again and sorry for not getting back earlier, totally forgot

Answer (score 2):

Add more memory to Maven:

1. (**Windows**) Set the Variable name to MAVEN_OPTS and set the Variable value to **-Xmx1024m** (or more)
2. In **IntellijIdea** Settings -> Build, Excecution, Deployment ->Build tools-> Maven -> Runner -> add param (**-Xmx1024m** (or more)) to VM Options.